# SpriteKit dismiss UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit scene I have a pauseView that displays a UIView over the scene, and on the UIView I've created a button in IB to remove the view but when the view disappears, In order to resume the game the user has to hit the pause button a second time. Is there a way to dismiss the view and resume the game?

The pause game method used to display the subview:

```
-(void)pauseGame {

    if (self.gameIsPaused == NO) {
        [self.view addSubview:pauseView];
        self.gameIsPaused = YES;
        self.scene.view.paused = YES;
    } else {
        self.gameIsPaused = NO;
        self.scene.view.paused = NO;
    }
}
```

And in the pause layer:

```
- (IBAction)resume:(id)sender {
    [gameScene pauseGame];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `[sender removeFromSuperview];`, not `self`. Assuming "pause layer" is a subclass of a SKNode rather than a UIView subclass.

If that's not it, check if the pause button has been added twice. Ie could have been an accidental copy & paste in IB.

Comment: Well the pause layer (subclass of UIView) is being dismissed correctly, but the gameScene remains paused even after I close the pause layer, until I hit pause again. I put a breakpoint in the pause method and looks like it is not being called when I send the '[gameScene pauseGame];' method.

Comment: gameScene is probably nil then

Comment: Well after a lot of fiddling around, I've managed to get GameScene to call the pause method, but the problem is that the GameScene is being reinitialized after closing the pause layer for some reason and resetting the `self.gameIsPaused` value and others. Is there a way I can keep a strong reference to the GameScene so it properly resumes with the correct values?